# Como converter variável para String?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt-4

Tenho uma função que pega um código do banco de dados postgreSQL  e visualizo setando no `QLabel` com a função `setText()`.

O problema é que esse código vem do banco de dados em formato estranho, entre parênteses e vírgula. Exemplo: `(VI1,)`.

Como retirar esses parênteses e vírgulas?

Função:

```
def cod_via(self,nome_via):
    cursor = self.connectBanco()
    sql = "SELECT cod_via FROM espacial.via WHERE nome_via = '%s'"%nome_via 

    cursor.execute(sql)  
    resultado = cursor.fetchall()                   

    return resultado
```

Exibo com:

```
cod = instancia_sql.cod_via(nome_via)

self.dlg.label_resul.setText(str(cod))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O problema é que esse código vem do banco de dados em formato
>   estranho, entre parênteses e vírgula. Exemplo: `(VI1,)`. Como retirar
>   esses parênteses e vírgulas?

Isso acontece porque o método [`cursor.fetchall()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) retorna uma lista de tuplas, o ideal é usar o método [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html), que irá retornar uma linha ou `None`. Veja:

```
def cod_via(self, nome_via):
    cursor = self.connectBanco()
    sql = "SELECT cod_via FROM espacial.via WHERE nome_via = '%s'" % nome_via 

    cursor.execute(sql)
    resultado = cursor.fetchone()

    return resultado
```

Comment: Pessoal resolvi. Além de usar fetchone() é necessário utilizar lope para percorrer o resultado.

Comment: Ficou assim: cursor.execute(sql) 
        resultado = cursor.fetchone() 
        for resp in resultado:
            resultado=resp;                 
        return resultado

Answer (score 1):

Ele vem em formato de [tupla](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple).

Você pode pegar ele assim:

```
t = ('a', 'b', 1, 2);
t2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 );

print "t[0]: ", t[0]
print "t2[1:5]: ", t2[1:5]
```

Resultado:

```
t[0]:  a
t2[1:5]:  [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

No seu caso tente `cod[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Se não for retornar mais de um resultado pode usar o `join`:

```
return ''.join(resultado)
```